# iPhone private APIs

Tags: ios, iphone-privateapi

How to add private APIs and frameworks to an iPhone App. Like Apple80211.

Comment: do you want apple to reject your application...?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're asking "how do I call a function declared in a private API", [this app](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-wireless/) will show you how. Look in `-[MSNetworksManager init]`.

`void * dlopen(const char*, int)` is the function you're looking for, declared in `dlcfn.h`, used like this:

```
int (*scan)(void *, NSArray **, void *);
void *libHandle = dlopen("/System/Library/Frameworks/Preferences.framework/Preferences", RTLD_LAZY);
scan = dlsym(libHandle, "Apple80211Scan");
```

Answer (score 1):

Please do not use any private APIs since there is every chance that Apple will reject your application.

Comment: :) I was actually aware of the consequences, but i just basically wanted to check out some features at my end. So my question still stands :)